# セット商品の最適な内訳を選択するアルゴリズムを知りたい

Tags: アルゴリズム

顧客から商品の購入依頼があります。
その商品を最適なセット商品の購入に変更して、最安の値段で購入したいです。
よいアルゴリズムがあれば教えていただきたいです。

例）
顧客からの購入依頼
　商品A　20個　単価200円　合計金額4000円
　商品B　10個　単価300円　合計金額3000円

セット商品
　商品ABセット　金額　450円
内訳
　　　商品A　1個
　　　商品B　1個

上記の場合、顧客が購入するものとして商品ABセットを10個購入して、商品Aを単品で10個購入するのが最適です。
このような最適な組み合わせを選ぶ良いアルゴリズムがあれば教えていただきたいです。
プログラムの言語は問いません。
よろしくお願いします。

追記
自身で調べたのですが、動的計画法を使用すれば求めれそうと思いましたがどのように適用したらよいのか分からない状態です。
動的計画法を利用した方法でもそれ以外の方法でも良いので教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 「このような最適な組み合わせを選らぶ良いアルゴリズムがあれば教えていただきたいです。」とのことですが、ご自身で調べられたことは何もないのでしょうか？重複回答しないためにも、ありましたら質問に追記お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

以下の方法で求めることができました。

商品A，商品Bの顧客の依頼数：   `na`, `nb`
商品A，商品B，商品ABの単価：   `pa`, `pb`, `pab`
商品A，商品B，商品ABの購入数： `x`, `y`, `z`
購入数での合計金額：           `t`

とおくと，下記の関係があります。

```
na =  1 * x +  0 * y +   1 * z
nb =  0 * x +  1 * y +   1 * z
t  = pa * x + pb * y + pab * z
```

これをベクトル `n = (na, nb, t)`, `w = (x, y, z)` と行列 `A`（3x3）で表すと

```
n = A * w
w = inv(A) * n
```

となり， `n` から `w` ，すなわち `t` から `x`, `y`, `z` を求める式が得られます。

そこで，`t` を0から徐々に増やしていき「 `x`, `y`, `z` が全て0以上の整数になる」ところを見つければ， `t` が最小となる `x`, `y`, `z` が得られます。なお， `t` は `pa`, `pb`, `pab` の最大公約数の倍数なので， この最大公約数を単位に増やしていきます。

Python（3.9以上が必要）の実装例とその出力を示します。

```
import numpy as np
import math

na, nb = 20, 10
pa, pb, pab = 200, 300, 450

A = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [pa, pb, pab]])
t_limit = pa * na + pb * nb
t_step = math.gcd(pa, pb, pab)  # greatest common divisor

for t in range(0, t_limit + 1, t_step):
    x, y, z = np.linalg.solve(A, np.array([na, nb, t]))
    x, y, z = round(x), round(y), round(z)
    if not pa * x + pb * y + pab * z == t:
        continue
    if x >= 0 and y >= 0 and z >= 0:
        break

print(f'A: {x}, B: {y}, AB: {z}')
print(f'Total: {t:,}')
```

```
A: 10, B: 0, AB: 10
Total: 6,500
```

Comment: セット商品の種類が増えたらどうなるのでしょうか

Comment: 商品の種類を増やすのは行列等の次数を増やせばよさそうですが，セット商品の種類を増やすのはそう単純ではなく私には良い方法が思いつきません。

Answer (score 1):

商品A、商品B、商品ABの購入数をそれぞれ `x0`, `x1`, `x2` とすると、

```
x0, x1, x2 は整数
x0 >= 0, x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0
1 * x0 + 0 * x1 + 1 * x2 = 20 (商品Aの購入依頼が20個)
0 * x0 + 1 * x1 + 1 * x2 = 10 (商品Bの購入依頼が10個)
```

という制約の下で、

```
200 * x0 + 300 * x1 + 450 * x2
```

を最小化する、という問題となります。

このような問題は、整数計画問題と呼ばれ、答えを求める汎用のライブラリが存在します。

例えば、Python-MIP を使うと、以下のように解けます。

```py
from mip import Model, minimize, xsum, INTEGER

sets = [((1, 0), 200), ((0, 1), 300), ((1, 1), 450)]
target = (20, 10)

m = Model()
x = m.add_var_tensor((len(sets),), "x", var_type = INTEGER)
m.objective = minimize(xsum([p_i for _, p_i in sets] * x))
for i, t in enumerate(target):
    m += xsum([n_i[i] for n_i, _ in sets] * x) == t
m.verbose = 0
m.optimize()
print(int(m.objective.x), [int(x_i.x) for x_i in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

例題の商品を

商品A　2個　セット価格400円
商品B　2個　セット価格600円
商品C　2個　セット価格450円

個数を重さ、価格を価値にして、重さの総和を設定し、

0-1ナップサック問題の動的計画法を使うもので最適解が得られるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: それだと、計算するまでもなく、常に商品Aを使うのが最安になってしまうように見えます。あと、「0-1ナップサック問題」だと、同じ商品を最大1個までしか買えません。